# Fetch files and remove them from source if succesful

Tags: linux, ansible

I've been using Ansible to fetch files from Windows nodes to a Linux node for some time with good results.
I would now like the nodes to remove fetched files once they have uploaded successfully.

However, since I'm fetching from lots of endpoints in various states, some files occasionally fail to transfer - and I'm having trouble using Ansible to skip those files, and those files only.

Here's what I have so far:

```yaml
- name: Find .something files
    ansible.windows.win_find:
      paths: 'C:\Some\Path'
      patterns: [ '*.something' ]
      recurse: yes
      age_stamp: ctime
      age: -1w
    register: found_files
  - name: Create destination directory
    file:
      path: "/some/path/{{inventory_hostname}}/"
      state: directory
    delegate_to: localhost
  - name: Fetch .something files
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: "/some/path/{{inventory_hostname}}/"
      flat: yes
      validate_checksum: no
    with_items: "{{ found_files.files }}"
    register: item.sync_result
    ignore_errors: yes
      msg: "Would remove {{ item.path }}"
    when: sync_result is succeeded
    with_items: "{{ found_files.files }}"
```

The problem is, the `sync_result` variable seems to apply to each node instead of each file - that is, if one file has failed to transfer, no files will be deleted.

I've tried various loops and lists and could not get it to work.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the goal is to: find files > send them over somewhere > remove them. Then remove the files listed from the find task. You will not have an issue with _lots of endpoints in various states_ since the list of files you fetch is actually the representation of the state of the node, done via the find task. Else, there is something missing in your question that I fail to understand.

Comment: That was my inital approach - but my concern is that a file will fail to fetch, but be removed since it was registered on the source node in the find task before fetching them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
  - name: Find .something files
    ansible.windows.win_find:
      paths: 'C:\Some\Path'
      patterns: [ '*.something' ]
      recurse: yes
      age_stamp: ctime
      age: -1w
    register: find_something

  - name: Create destination directory
    file:
      path: "/some/path/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"
      state: directory
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Fetch .something files
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: "/some/path/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"
      flat: yes
      validate_checksum: no
    loop: "{{ find_something.files }}"
    register: fetch_sync
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Delete successfully fetched files
    file:
      path: "{{ item.file }}"
      state: absent
    loop: "{{ fetch_sync.results | select('succeeded') }}"
    # If you are using ansible < 2.10 you need to cast to list i.e.
    # loop: "{{ fetch_sync.results | select('succeeded') | list }}"
```

Comment: Hi, This throws up the error: `Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f6e7dc47ca8>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.`. I'm not sure what's going wrong...

Comment: You are using an old version of ansible (< 2.10). In this case the result of `select` must be mapped explicitly to a list. Updated the answer with an example. Meanwhile, I suggest you upgrade your ansible version.